# props data is not working in componentDidMount using react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have been struggling for the last 24 hrs about this one.
The problem is that, I am passing props in my parent class and calling the props data in my child component. When I check in render method the data shows correctly, but when calling it in `componentDidMount` it shows null.

**Here is the sample of my code**

```
class parent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
      day:'monday',
      data:[],
      data1:[]
    }
  }

  back () {
    this.props.navigator.pop();
  }

  Mon(){
    var record=[];
    this.state.data.map((data) => {
      if(data.frequency[0].day == 'Monday'){
        record.push(data);
      }
    });
    this.setState({data1:record});
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
  //here i am getting the data from service and set the data to the state
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.Maincontainer}>
        <View style={styles.navbar}>
          <View style={styles.navbarContainer}>
            <View style={styles.navbarIcon}>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.back()}>
                <Image
                  style={styles.menu2}
                  source={require('image!nav_arrow')} />
                <Text style={styles.navbuttonText}>Back</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.navbarText}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>Title</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.navbarButton}>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.subMainContainer}>
          <View style={styles.weekHeader}>
            <View style={styles.weekRow}>
              <Text style={styles.text} onPress={this.Mon.bind(this)}>Mon</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.listBody}>
            {this.state.data1.length == 0 ?(
              <List data={this.state.data} />
            ) : (
              <List data={this.state.data1}/>
            )}
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In my child component, I want to display the data in a `ListView` which is taken from the parent component

```
class List extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
       }),
       isLoading: true
    };
  }
 componentDidMount(){ //**here props data shows empty**
    alert("didMount:"+JSON.stringify(this.props.data));
    var data=this.props.data
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data),
      isLoading: false
    });
  }
  render() { //**In this alert it shows correct data**
    alert("data:"+JSON.stringify(this.props.data));
   if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }
    return(
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderSchedule.bind(this)}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}/>
      );
  }
  renderLoadingView(){
    return(
       <View style={styles.loading}>
       <ActivityIndicatorIOS
                size='large'/>
        <Text>
          Loading Schedule...
        </Text>
      </View>
      );
  }
  renderSchedule(data){
    return(
      <View style={styles.ListContainer}>
          <View style={styles.subContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.classText}>Class Name: {data.name}</Text>
             {data.frequency[0].day == null ? (
              <Text style={styles.Day}>Day: {data.frequency[0].date}</Text>
              ):
            <Text style={styles.Day}>Day: {data.frequency[0].day}</Text>
          }
          </View>
          <View style={styles.subContainer1}>
            <Text style={styles.startTime}>Start: {data.frequency[0].from}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.endTime}>End: {data.frequency[0].to}</Text>
          </View>
      </View>
      )
  }
}
```

Here what i want is that initially i need to display the total data,when click on the text parent class the data need to be changed.I want to show the data in ListView.I already explain above about my problem,So can any one give me suggestions that how to solve my problem, Any help much appreciated

Comment: Hmm... interesting because `render` invokes before `componentDidMount`. Could you create a simple fiddle exmaple?

Comment: Works fine for me on a JSFiddle. Can you try just passing in a dummy prop like 

`<List testProp={1234} />`

And check that?

Comment: @Glitch100 when i try like that it's working,can you please check my code whether i wrote any wrong in my code

Comment: just a reminder, your render function initially returns `renderLoadingView()` which doesn't use state at all in the view. You are updating state that is not used in the view inside of your `componentDidMount`, there is no guarantee anything will update correctly.

Comment: Also I don't see you passing anything to your `renderSchedule(data)` except for `this` it should look like this inside of reder row `renderRow={(rowData) => this.renderSchedule(rowData)}`

Comment: @AKADER i am passing <List data={this.state.data}/> then in child component componentDidMount it shows the data when click on text Mon in parent class i changed the data in state and pass it to child,But in child component componentDidMount is not calling when change the data in parent state, but in render alert it shows the changed data

Answer (score 6):

My guess would be that the alert in `componentDidMount()` is empty because it only called once, at a time when data is still empty, while `render()` is called on each change of state or props.

I would expect the flow of alerts to look something like this:

- Alert called from child's render: "data: (empty)"
- Alert called from child's didMount: "didMount:(empty)"
- User clicks something in parent, state change, re-render triggered
- Alert called from child's render: "data: FOO-content"

React does NOT call `componentDidMount()` on the second pass. If you want your datasource to be populated on EACH update of the child, you will need to add a `componentDidUpdate()` method to your child, with copy of the code you have inside `componentDidMount()`.

As a general note: I would advise you to read [React's explanation of component lifecycle and methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html). I have a feeling that the preparation you are doing inside `componentDidMount()` is probably better placed elsewhere:

- creating a DataSource and initial fill with data from props: in `getInitialState()`
- updating Datasource with data from new props: in `componentWillReceiveProps()`

Answer (score 0):

I found in React generally that if I want to prepare the initial state of my component based on `this.props` then I should do it in `componentDidUpdate` instead of `componentDidMount`. Components aren't *mounted* with populated props from the parent component, only *updated* with them.

I noticed this when doing normal React and doing `console.log(this.props)` in the `render` method of my child component. It would log initally as empty, then log again populated with the props. If I called a `this.setState` in `componentDidMount` then the population of `this.props` occurs in the *third* render. This is because calling `this.setState` in `componentDidMount` triggered a pre-update render.

I hope this makes sense and applies to your situation - I arrived at your question looking for a solution to similar behaviour.